# MS Project 2010 Filter and Highlights

Tags: microsoft-project

I'd like to know if there is a way to highlight dates that differs from one another.

I have two columns "Baseline Finish Date" and "Re-forecast Finish Date" and I would like to highlight the dates that for each task, is different in those columns.

Meaning the tasks that suffered a re-forecast due to other circumstances, and does not equal to the original dates.

I also would like a filter that does the same thing as above, showing only this different date tasks.

Comment: I've tried to do it, but I didn't find a way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Johnny - Feel free to visit our http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/ site and pose this question and make your case. I'd be interested to hear what the community thinks about these MS Project questions. In the past we've allowed them, and that  has set the precedent for us to continue to allow them.

Answer (score 1):

I just use a number field with a formula inside that shows the difference between Baseline and the Finish date. If it shows anything other than zero, you're off. Seems to work great.